# How to get past "CD-ROM couldn't be mounted" when installing Ubuntu Server 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, server, mount, usb-drive

I have been trying to install Ubuntu Server version 16.04.3 onto my PC through a USB drive and have been getting the same message after I select the keyboard layout.

---

[!!] Detect and mount CD-ROM

Your installation CD-ROM couldn't be mounted. This probably means that the CD-ROM was not in the drive. If so you can insert it and try again.

Retry mounting the CD-ROM?

```
<YES>                            <NO>
```

---

I have tried a few different ways on Ask-Ubuntu to fix it already (changing USB ports) but I haven't been able to find a working solution for this Ubuntu Server Version. Currently my PC does not have a Optical drive. Will I have to buy one and use a CD or is it possible for me to do it on USB?

If you need to know my Motherboard is an MSI Z270 Gaming Pro Carbon. It uses a UEFI/LEGACY BIOS.

update: Network installer has not worked. I have tried Ubuntu Mini but when I select it on my boot menu the computer shows an error and starts Windows 10

another update: I created the bootable disk using Rufus Version 2.16 on Windows 10. MD5Sum has told me that the ISO file was downloaded correctly

Thanks in Advance

Jaiden

Comment: did you try the network installer image?

Comment: 1. Did you check with `md5sum` that the iso file was downloaded correctly? ; 2. How did you create the USB boot drive (which tool did you use, and from what operating system)?